# pandas groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Сделал игрушечный датасет из трёх столбцов: **person**, **season**, **target**. В колонке **target** три значения: 0, 1 и 2.

Создаётся новая колонка:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['person', 'season'])['target'].transform('size')
```

Т.е. находим количество записей (строк) для каждого **person** в каждом **season** при всех значениях **target**.

Теперь надо уточнить значения (количество строк) для каждого случая **target**. Т.е. подсчитать сколько для каждого person в каждом **season** записей где **target** `== 1`, `== 2`, `== 0`.

Делаю так:

```
df['target_1'] = df.groupby(['person', 'season'])['target' == 1].transform('size')
```

Но получается ошибка `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`.

Искал по запросу *pandas groupby multiple columns*, но там не то. Лямбду тут не приспособить, `apply` не к месту, если брать `map`, то придётся отказаться от `transform()`. Пытался с `filter()`, но не справился.
Ещё пишут что есть вариант решения - для каждого из трёх моих случаев (`target ==1,==2,==0`) создаётся своя колонка, потом они сливаются (**merge**). Но мне кажется, что задача несложная, и должно быть такое же несложное решение.

Короче - что делать?

И отдельный вопрос - как искать по английски, если есть условие `['target' == 1]`.
Ну, то есть, если `groupby multiply columns` это понятно, а вот это дополнительное условие?

Comment: "И отдельный вопрос" - так и задавайте отдельно!

Comment: Сначала нужно вычленить данные по условию, а потом делать группировку. типа df[df['target']==1].groupby ...`

Comment: df['1] = df[df['target']==1].groupby(['person', 'season']).transform('size')    --> TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU Да пример то не сложно сделать: `import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n), 
    'season': np.random.randint(1, 5, size=n),
    'target': np.random.randint(0, 3, size=n),
})`

Comment: @CrazyElf, я сейчас не за компьютер ом, но в теории можно сделать группировку по всем трём столбцам и применить .transform("count")

Comment: @MaxU Я что-то такое пытался сам сделать, но, кажется автор хочет отдельными столбцами эту инфу получить, а я не могу сообразить как столбец на три отдельных раскидать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я без примера выходных данных не очень понимаю - чего хочет автор вопроса

Comment: @MaxU Ну, он вроде что-то такое хочет, что мы оба догадались - `count`, но в отдельных столбцах `Target_0`, `Target_1`, `Target_2`. Если я правильно понял.

Comment: @CrazyElf, мне кажется это он так пытается посчитать число вхождений для каждой группы - он потом собрался все это обьединить при помощи merge

Comment: Предлагаю дать автору время привести в вопросе пример входных данных и желаемый результат, чтобы мы тут не гадали )

Comment: pandas.Series.value_counts https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: Пример создания данных от @CrazyElf - норм. На выходе хочу получить один столбец с числом вхождений для каждой группы. Либо три столбца, где частично будут null, а потом их merge.

Comment: @splash58 pandas.DataFrame.value_counts() не годится т.к. это подсчёт всех уникальных сочетаний строк, без группировки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то я всё-равно до конца не понял. Если один столбец хотите получить, то делаете тоже самое, только для трёх столбцов группировка:

```
df['count_3'] = df.groupby(['person', 'season', 'target'])['target'].transform('size')
df
```

Вывод:

```
    person  season  target  count   count_3
0        3       3       0      2         1
1        5       1       0      5         2
2        2       2       0      2         1
...
```

Или вот вам 3 столбца с `NA`:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['person', 'season', 'target'])['target'].count().unstack()
df_new
```

Вывод:

```
        target    0   1   2
person  season          
     1       1  2.0 NaN 1.0
             2  2.0 2.0 4.0
             4  2.0 1.0 NaN
...
```

P.S. Если кто будет экспериментировать, то вот искусственные данные:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n), 
    'season': np.random.randint(1, 5, size=n),
    'target': np.random.randint(0, 3, size=n),
})
```